# start/stop and handler custom scheduler via http

Tags: go, timer

I want to create a scheduler so that it executes a task every second for example, but also would like to have and http interface to stop/start the scheduler and get more stats/info, after reading more about [timers & tickers](https://mmcgrana.github.io/2012/09/go-by-example-timers-and-tickers.html), [channels](https://gobyexample.com/channels) and [gorutines](https://gobyexample.com/goroutines) I came out with this:

https://gist.github.com/nbari/483c5b382c795bf290b5

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

var timer *time.Ticker

func scheduler(seconds time.Duration) *time.Ticker {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(seconds * time.Second)
    go func() {
        for t := range ticker.C {
            // do stuff
            fmt.Println(t)
        }
    }()
    return ticker
}

func Start(timer *time.Ticker) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        timer = scheduler(1)
        w.Write([]byte("Starting scheduler"))
    })
}

func Stop(timer *time.Ticker) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        timer.Stop()
        w.Write([]byte("Stoping scheduler"))
    })
}

func main() {
    timer = scheduler(1)
    http.Handle("/start", Start(timer))
    http.Handle("/stop", Stop(timer))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

The above code is working but I have a global "timer" variable, I would like to know if there is a better way to implement this and also a way for handle more than 1 scheduler, currently thinking on probably implementing kind of a container for all the scheduler but would like to have some feedbacks that could help me find clever solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way:

You should use channels here, and, as you suggested, some data structure to hold more schedulers.

I came up with this, it's a most basic working example of what I'd do:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

// a scheduler runs f on every receive on t and exits when receiving from quit is non-blocking
type scheduler struct {
    t    <-chan time.Time
    quit chan struct{}
    f    func()
}

// a schedulerPool holds multiple schedulers
type schedulerPool struct {
    schedulers map[int]scheduler //I used a map here so you can use more clever keys
    counter    int
    mut        sync.Mutex
}

func newPool() *schedulerPool {
    return &schedulerPool{
        schedulers: make(map[int]scheduler),
    }
}

// start adds and starts a new scheduler that will execute f every interval.
// It returns the generated ID for the scheduler, or an error.
func (p *schedulerPool) start(interval time.Duration, f func()) (int, error) {
    p.mut.Lock()
    defer p.mut.Unlock()
    index := p.counter
    p.counter++

    if _, ok := p.schedulers[index]; ok {
        return 0, errors.New("key already in use")
    }

    sched := scheduler{
        t:    time.NewTicker(interval).C,
        quit: make(chan struct{}),
        f:    f,
    }

    p.schedulers[index] = sched
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-sched.t:
                sched.f()
            case <-sched.quit:
                return
            }
        }
    }()
    return index, nil
}

// stop stops the scheduler with the given ID.
func (p *schedulerPool) stop(index int) error {
    p.mut.Lock()
    defer p.mut.Unlock()

    sched, ok := p.schedulers[index]
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("does not exist")
    }

    close(sched.quit)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    // get a new pool
    pool := newPool()

    // start a scheduler
    idx1, err := pool.start(time.Second, func() { fmt.Println("hello 1") })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // start another scheduler
    idx2, err := pool.start(time.Second, func() { fmt.Println("hello 2") })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // wait some time
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)

    // stop the second scheduler
    err = pool.stop(idx2)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // wait some more
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)

    // stop the first scheduler
    err = pool.stop(idx1)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Check it out on the [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/2LzZbycLfq).

Note that there is no guarantee that the first scheduler will run six times in total and the second one three times.

Also note a few other things I've done:

- Map access has to be synchronized
- Generating IDs must be synchronized
- You should check if the key is actually in the map
- Use channels to start, stop and control schedulers (for example, add a channel `beep` to have a scheduler dump something to the console (like `"beep"`))
- Define a type for the exact signature of function you want to execute, for example `type schedFunc func(int, int)`

Obviously, you need to wrap that stuff inside of http handlers, probably take the ID or parameters from the querystring, or some other fancy stuff. This is just for demonstration.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but if I am right time.NewTicker returns a channel and I think I am currently using them here: https://gist.github.com/nbari/483c5b382c795bf290b5#file-scheduler-go-L15, also why not use timer.Stop? what is the difference of creating another channel (quit) to stop the timer ?

Comment: @nbari: from the docs for Ticker and Timer: "Stop does not close the channel, to prevent a read from the channel succeeding incorrectly". Your for range loop will never exit.

Comment: I am a little confuse, since in the tick_test.go they use  ``Stop()`` and seems to be working, please check https://golang.org/src/time/tick_test.go lines 28-35, basically I don't understand why I need a control channel (quit) just for stoping a previous opened channel, could you please elaborate more on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I after reading this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797754/ticker-stop-behaviour-in-golang I got it better, if changing the int on the map to a string could help to avoid the "sync" or why indeed the for synchronising using ``mut.Lock/Unlock`` ?

Comment: No. Map access has to be synchronized, maps are not thread-safe.